# How Can I make a TextWidget wrap in Row?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How Can I make the orange text break to the start of the row instead of breaking to the start of itself?

TextWidget Wrap in Row:
[image: TextWidget Wrap in Row]

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot if possible?

Comment: @SahebSingh There is screen shot above

Comment: @Matheus you need to ellipsis the text if the text are long one. As you already have a very less space on popup screen

Comment: Ok so you want the black and orange text in the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Richtext like that:

```
return Container(
        height: 175,
        width: 150,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, top: 100,),
            child: RichText(
                text: const TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
            text: 'I agree with the ',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 12,
            ),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: 'privacy_policiesfkads;ljfklas;dj',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.orange,
              fontSize: 12,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ]))));
```

you should be able to achieve everything you want in terms of design and scaling and also positioning...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) instead of Row? Less code, more possibilities.